# MongoDB: Using reference as key and manually adding a value

Tags: mongodb, reference

I am very new to Mongo DB and have the following problem.
Lets assume I have this document structure, where the user Joe Bloggs watches a content, which is referenced with the id 5000:

```
db.users.insert({
  forname: 'Joe', 
  surname: 'Bloggs', 
  DOB: 12061989, 
  watch: [5000]
});

db.media_content.insert({
  _id: 5000,
  content_name: 'Film XYZ', 
  durations_min: 45, 
  media_type: 'video',
});
```

I would like to add that the user Joe Bloggs watched only 35 minutes of the Film XYZ, which is however 45min long. How would I add this and what would the query look like if I want to demonstrate that Joe Bloggs watched Film XYZ with the amount of time of 35 min.

--- **UPDATE** ---

Instead of doing the updates, I coded it all again so I can try it out:

```
db.users.insert({
  forname: 'Tom',
  surname: 'Smith',
  DOB: 22081989,
  watch: [{
            media_id: 6000,
            stream_min: 35
            }]
});

db.media_content.insert({
  _id: 6000,
  content_name: 'Film XYZ', 
  durations_min: 45, 
  media_type: 'video',
});

var minutes_watched = db.users.find(
{
    "forname": "Tom", 
    "surname": "Smith", 
    "DOB": 22081989, 
    "watch.media_id": 6000
}, 
{ 
    "watch": { 
        "$elemMatch": { "media_id": 6000 } 
    } 
}).watch[0].minutes_watched;
```

I thought I got it working but I still get the message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure your document schema in such a way that the `watch` array will transform into an embedded document that has both the reference id and the minutes watched properties, instead of an array with just the id values. Something like this [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update should do:

```
db.users.update({
        "forname": "Joe", 
        "surname": "Bloggs", 
        "DOB": 12061989, 
        "watch": 5000
    },
    {
        "$push": {
            "watch": {
                "media_id": 5000,
                "minutes_watched": 35
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The above updates the users document for the user "Joe" to add an embedded document in the `watch` array that has the above properties. To tidy things up you can then [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) the other `watch` array element with value 5000

```
db.users.update({
        "forname": "Joe", 
        "surname": "Bloggs", 
        "DOB": 12061989, 
        "watch": 5000
    },
    {
        "$pull": { "watch": 5000 }
    }
);
```

Since you now have the actual duration watched and the media id details all embedded in the user document, you can then query the two collections given the media id to get the minutes watched (using [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) on the `watch` array to project just that field) and the movie details like this:

```
var minutes_watched = db.users.findOne(
    {
        "forname": "Joe", 
        "surname": "Bloggs", 
        "DOB": 12061989, 
        "watch.media_id": 5000
    }, 
    { 
        "watch": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "media_id": 5000 } 
        } 
    }).watch[0].minutes_watched;

var movie = db.media_content.findOne({"_id": 5000});
```

**EDIT**

If a user watches 2 more movies, one say with id 4567 for some good 20 minutes out of a total of 80 minutes and another with id 1234 for 58 minutes, you can simply push these details to the `watch` array using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#use-each-with-addtoset-operator) with [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#use-each-with-addtoset-operator) like this:

```
db.users.update({
        "forname": "Joe", 
        "surname": "Bloggs", 
        "DOB": 12061989
    },
    {
        "$addToSet": {
            "watch": { 
                $each: [ 
                    { "media_id": 4567, "minutes_watched": 20 }, 
                    { "media_id": 1234, "minutes_watched": 58 }                 
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

A query on the user "Joe" `db.users.findOne({"forname": "Joe"})` will yield the updated document:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553d143ac96712b936005274"),
    "forname" : "Joe",
    "surname" : "Bloggs",
    "DOB" : 12061989,
    "watch" : [ 
        {
            "media_id" : 5000,
            "minutes_watched" : 35
        }, 
        {
            "media_id" : 4567,
            "minutes_watched" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "media_id" : 1234,
            "minutes_watched" : 58
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! Would this work if the user watches 2 or more films too?

Comment: @clde Yes, quite possible indeed. I've updated my answer to this effect.

Comment: The update works but when I query the part that is stored in the var minutes_watched, this problem arises: TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of null. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you show me the query? There's a possibility that the watch array doesn't have such element?

Comment: I think it works now since no error is arising, however, I don't see the result because the query is stored in the variabel. How would I see the result? Sorry for asking such stupid question!

Comment: If you are using mongo shell, you could do `print(minuted_watched)`, the value will be displayed in the shell.

Comment: I posted the code below since it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's not working because you are using the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor method which returns a cursor instead of the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne) method which returns the actual document. Change your query to `var minutes_watched = db.users.findOne(...).watch[0].minutes_watched;` with the appropriate query and projection operators, that will give you the variable with a value.

Comment: Right! Now the error is gone but when I use print(minutes_watched) it says undefined. I am using Mongo in the Mac Terminal.

Comment: @clde It's undefined because you are referencing a different field. Looking at your update, you are now using a new field to store the minutes watched; `stream_min`. Change your query to `var minutes_watched = db.users.findOne(...).watch[0].stream_min; print(minutes_watched);` you will get the value `35` displayed in your shell.